# SQL UPDATE SET columns to be equal to MIN & MAX values from a related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (T1 & T2), and I would like to update:

- T1 `start_year` based on T2 `start_year` minimum value where make ids match
- T1 `end_year` based on T2 `end_year` maximum value  where make ids match

so the end results based on the example image would be like this:

---

1     Abarth     2014     NULL

---

2     AC          1990      2001

---

3     Acura      1996      NULL

---

Here are the tables:

T1:

[image: T1]

T2:

[image: T2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my sql `update ... join ... set` syntax, with an aggreate query on `t2`. Consider the following query:

```
update t1
inner join (
    select 
        make_id, 
        min(start_year) min_start_year, 
        max(end_year) max_end_year
    from t2
    group by make_id
) t2 on t2.make_id = t1.id
set t1.start_year = t2.min_start_year, t1.end_year = t2.max_end_year
```

---

Edit from the comments: to set the end_year to null if any end_year in t2 is null:

```
update t1
inner join (
    select 
        make_id, 
        min(start_year) min_start_year, 
        max(end_year) max_end_year,
        max(end_year is null) end_year_has_null
    from t2
    group by make_id
) t2 on t2.make_id = t1.id
set 
    t1.start_year = t2.min_start_year, 
    t1.end_year = case 
        when t2.end_year_has_null then null 
        else t2.max_end_year 
    end
```

Comment: This is working like a charm! Thank you so much! However, I would like to add an if statement when T2 `end_year` is 'NULL' then T1 `end_year` should be `NULL` as well.

Comment: @Csaba: do you mean of *any* `t2.end_year` of a given `make_id` is null, or if *all* of them are `null`?

Comment: Good question! I think if any of `t2.end_year` of a given `make_id` is null woud be the correct way doing it.

Comment: I've changed MAX function to `MAX(IFNULL(end_year, NULL)) AS max_end_year` but this only works if all of the `end_year` values are `NULL`

Comment: @Csaba: I edited my answer to add a query for your use case.